# Is there an efficient way to join an array of strings into a single string in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

My goal is to write a function that takes an array of strings, and returns a single string containing all of the input strings combined.

For example, in Python this could be done this way:

```
result = ''.join(['hello', 'solidity', 'world'])  # hellosolidityworld
```

My current implementation doesn't seem efficient at all:

```
function concat(string[] memory words) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    // calculate output length
    uint256 bytesLength;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        bytesLength += bytes(words[i]).length;
    }

    bytes memory output = new bytes(bytesLength);
    uint256 currentByte;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        bytes memory bytesWord = bytes(words[i]);
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < bytesWord.length; j++) {
            output[currentByte] = bytesWord[j];
            currentByte++;
        }
    }

    return string(output);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the function by using `abi.encodePacked()` that combines multiple values and returns a dynamic-length byte array (type `bytes`).

Since `string` in Solidity is effectively stored the same way as a byte array, you can then easily convert the `output` byte array to a string.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function concat(string[] calldata words) external pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory output;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            output = abi.encodePacked(output, words[i]);
        }

        return string(output);
    }
}
```

Try with `["hello", " ", "world"]` for example.

Comment: It does work but I think that it is not so efficient because it concatenates over and over. I think that assembly may help though I was looking for a working solution so don't have it yet..! Note that from `0.8.12` there is also `string.concat`.

Comment: @ClementWalter Thanks for pointing out the `string.concat`. It does effectively the same string as the `abi.encodePacked` in my answer, but `string.concat` is more clear what it does by the function name... If you're using the function as a part of the call, the looping doesn't matter because it's gas free anyway. And if you're using it as a part of a transaction, then it has the same complexity as if you did `tring.concat(words[0], words[1], words[2])` for a fixed amount of words. Note that you can't use an array as an input so that `string.concat(words)` won't work.

Comment: @ClementWalter I'm not aware of a way how to achieve the result in assembly more efficiently, but if you find it, please post it as an answer here.

Comment: I think that concat will take a free spot in memory and copy the iteratively all the arguments so that if you loop over a concat, you copy several time the same items

Comment: Petr Hejda you can see my answer below; I've achieved a fair amount of efficiency for long strings and long arrays, and at least as good as this for loop. Works for referenceTypes[] memory and valueType[] memory arrays

Comment: @ClementWalter Awesome work, thank you for finding a more efficient solution!

Answer (score 3):

I have just published an assembly implementation of javascript like `Array.join()` functions working for both reference types (`bytes[]` and `string[]`) and value types (`bytes2[]`, `uint16[]`, etc.). The lib is [here](https://github.com/ClementWalter/eth-projects-monorepo/blob/main/packages/eth-projects-contracts/contracts/lib/utils/Array.sol) and benchmarking it against a for loop with `string.concat` shows that it's up to 5x more efficient (depending on the number of strings and their length).

So using the above mentioned packages, it's like:

```
import {Array} from "@clemlaflemme.eth/contracts/lib/utils/Array.sol";


contract MyContract {

   using Array for string[];

   function foo(string[] memory arr) public pure returns (string memory) {
       return arr.join();
       // also return arr.join(","); for example
   }
}
```